# Why is the loop running infinite times?

Tags: c

Friends, my goal is to find the numbers with odd sums from the numbers 1-99 in C language and print them on the screen. To try, I narrowed the scale and wrote 5 instead of 99 in the code. However, there is a problem, this code, which I think works very well in the logic in my head, enters an endless loop. I couldn't find what to do. How do you think I fix this?

The expected output (think 5 instead of 99): "Sum of digits odd: 1 Sum of digits odd: 3"

```
int main() {
    int n, m, result, temp;

    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        temp = i;

        while (i > 0) {
            m = i % 10;
            result += m;
            i = i / 10;
        }

        if (result % 2 != 0) {
            printf("%d", temp);
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: The expected output does not match the code. Nothing in there can output "Sum of digits...".

Comment: Which loop is infinite? The outer is of course guaranteed to be infinit, waiting for i being 5 or greater, while the inner loop always makes sure that i ends up 0...

Comment: Consider your for loop. It uses `i` to increment from 1 to 4. But then the while loop modifies `i`. The test on that loop is `i` has to be greater than zero. So if/when it exits, `i` is equal to or less than zero. Will the `for` loop ever stop?

Comment: Might be because you modify `i` in `i = i/10` and you do this `while(i > 0)`, meaning at the end of each iteration of the for loop, `i` equals `0`. In python this would probably work if you were doing `for i in range(5)` because that precomputes the values of `i`.

Comment: In addition to everything else, `result` is uninitialized when read for the first time (`result += ...`). This is [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior). Initialize it first (`int result = 0;`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use `i++` in your loop, and yet use `i = i / 10` in that loop antill `i` is `0`. That means, that `i` gets stuck as `1`.

You'll either need another variable for the digit iteration, or to switch your use of `i` and `temp` so that `i` only gets changed by the loop's incrementation:

```
int main()    
{
  int n, m, result, temp;
  for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
  {
    result = 0;
    temp = i;
    while(temp>0)
    {
        m = temp % 10;
        result += m;
        temp = temp / 10;
    }
    if (result %2!=0)
    {
        printf("%d", i);
    }
  } 
  return 0;
}
```

Edit: I also missed that you forgot to initialize `result` with an initial value, so you basically keep adding to a garbage value. You should initialize it with `0` in each iteration.

Comment: Yes this stopped the cycle from repeating. But I'm still not getting the output I want. This is the output of your code: "1 2"

Comment: Look at my edit, based on chux's kind comment above me

Comment: Yes we did it! Actually, you did it. But I understood what you did it.

Answer (score 3):

You make a copy of `i` in `temp`.
But then you do not use `temp` and manipulate `i` in the inner loop.
Stick with your initial plan and only play with `temp` in the inner loop.

You probably also want to init/reset `result` at some point.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset the value of `i` after the `while` loop. As posted, value of `i` is zero after the `while` loop.